# Pygame Platformer Collisions

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am a python beginner and have recently started watching DaFluffyPotato's pygame platformer [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gABYM5M0ww&ab_channel=DaFluffyPotato), and attempting to code my own simple platformer. I have gotten to the collisions part of the tutorial, and attempted to model a player entity on a surface of tiles. I wanted to make the player (44x46) be able to stand on the tiles (32x32), however making it be larger than the tiles produces this weird visual effect.[effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV3Dn.gif).

Physics engine:

```
import pygame

class Entity:
    def __init__(self, game, etype, pos, size,):
        self.game = game
        self.type = etype
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.size=size
        self.velocity = [0, 0]
        self.collisions = {'up': False, 'down': False, 'right': False, 'left': False}

    def rect(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.size[0], self.size[1])

    def update(self, tilemap, movement=(0, 0)):
        self.collisions= {"up": False, "down": False, "right": False, "left": False}

        frame_movement = (movement[0] + self.velocity[0], movement[1] + self.velocity[1])

        self.pos[0] += frame_movement[0]
        entity_rect = self.rect()
        for rect in tilemap.physics_rects_around(self.pos):
            if entity_rect.colliderect(rect):
                if frame_movement[0] > 0:
                    entity_rect.right = rect.left
                    self.collisions["right"] = True
                if frame_movement[0] < 0:
                    entity_rect.left = rect.right
                    self.collisions["left"] = True
                self.pos[0] = entity_rect.x

        self.pos[1] += frame_movement[1]
        entity_rect = self.rect()
        for rect in tilemap.physics_rects_around(self.pos):
            if entity_rect.colliderect(rect):
                if frame_movement[1] > 0:
                    entity_rect.bottom= rect.top
                    self.collisions["down"] = True
                if frame_movement[1] < 0:
                    entity_rect.top = rect.bottom
                    self.collisions["up"] = True
                self.pos[1] = entity_rect.y


        self.velocity[1] = min(5, self.velocity[1] + 0.1)

        if self.collisions["down"] or self.collisions["up"]:
            self.velocity[1] = 0 



    def render(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.game.assets["player"], self.pos)
```

Tilemap:

```
import pygame

PHYSICS_TILES={"grass"}
NEIGHBOR_OFFSETS = [(-1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)]

class Tilemap:
    def __init__(self, game, tile_size):
        self.game=game
        self.tile_size = tile_size
        self.tilemap = {}
        self.offgrid_tiles = []

        for i in range(10):
            self.tilemap[str(3+i) + ";10"]={"type": "grass", "pos": (3+i, 10)}

    def tiles_around(self, pos):
        tiles = []
        tile_loc =(int(pos[0] // self.tile_size), int(pos[1] // self.tile_size))
        for offset in NEIGHBOR_OFFSETS:
            check_loc = str(tile_loc[0]+offset[0]) + ";" + str(tile_loc[1]+offset[1])
            if check_loc in self.tilemap:
                tiles.append(self.tilemap[check_loc])
        return tiles


    def physics_rects_around(self, pos):
        rects = []
        for tile in self.tiles_around(pos):
            if tile["type"] in PHYSICS_TILES:
                rects.append(pygame.Rect(tile["pos"][0]*self.tile_size, tile["pos"][1]*self.tile_size, self.tile_size, self.tile_size))
        return rects

    def render(self, surf):
        for tile in self.offgrid_tiles:
            surf.blit(self.game.assets[tile["type"]], tile["pos"])

        for loc in self.tilemap:
            tile = self.tilemap[loc]
            surf.blit(self.game.assets[tile["type"]],(tile["pos"][0]*self.tile_size, tile["pos"][1]*self.tile_size))
```

Game:

```
import sys
import pygame
from Scripts.entities import Entity
from Scripts.util import load_image
from Scripts.tilemap import Tilemap

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        
        self.movement= [False, False]
        self.ymovement= [False, False]

        self.assets = {
            "player": load_image("bonk.png"),
            "grass": load_image("grass.png")
        }

        self.tilemap = Tilemap(self, tile_size=32)

        self.player=Entity(self, "player", (100,50), (44, 46))


    def run(self):
        while True:
            
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

            self.tilemap.render(self.screen)


            self.player.update(self.tilemap, (self.movement[1] - self.movement[0], 0))
            self.player.render(self.screen)


            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                        self.player.velocity[1] = -3
                    if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                        self.movement[0] = True
                    if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                        self.movement[1] = True
                if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                        self.movement[0] = False
                    if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                        self.movement[1] = False
              
            
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)

Game().run()
```

I tested this with larger player entity sizes, and the effect is more pronounced.